# Why does using minChunks in CommonsChunkPlugin to extract all node_modules results in a bigger bundle?

Tags: webpack

Here are two webpack configs for extracting more or less the same stuff:

1. This extracts `node_modules` by explicitly giving it the names of dependencies read from `package.json`

   ```
   entry: {
       app: path.join(basePath, 'app.js'),
       vendor: Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies)
   },
   plugins: [
       new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
           name: 'vendor',
           filename: '[name].js',
       }),
   ]
   ```
2. This uses `minChunks` to extract all modules matching `node_modules` in their paths (this is also the [documented way](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#implicit-common-vendor-chunk))

   ```
   entry: {
       app: path.join(basePath, 'app.js'),
   },
   plugins: [
       new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
           name: 'vendor',
           minChunks: module => module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1,
       }),
   ]
   ```

They produce different bundle sizes, the second one has a bigger vendor bundle. And although it has a smaller app bundle, the total size is still bigger in the second one.

1. 15kb

   [image]
2. 20kB

   [image]

I analyzed the bundles and the latter one seems to include `style-loader` and `css-loader`

1. [image]
2. [image]

Firstly, why do the two configs produce different bundles, shouldn't they produce exactly the same bundle? And why does it include `style-loader` and `css-loader` (or any other loaders?) in the 2nd config?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin.js#L271 :) Place to start debugging?